# Is it possible to split bounties?

Tags: support, bounty

I'm about to award a bounty on a question. If it is possible I would like to split the bounty between two of the answers (one for elegance, one for effort). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can award more than one bounty on a question, so if they are to reward existing answers you can make that clear.

Comment: Note that multiple bounties on the same question by the same user does increment (actually doubles). See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/168244) Specially the question "Can I affect / divide part of my bounty to two (or more) users?"